# How to get the distinct of multiple fields in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I know that there're several existing questions like this one, but mine is little bit complicated (for me).

For example, I have index, data, log and flag these four tables.

```
index: id        program    compiler   flag_id   data_id
data:  id        machine    runtime    date      index_id
log:   index_id  data_id    log
flag:  id        flag_name
```

The flag_id, data_id and index_id indicate the corresponding table's main id. Those main id is auto incremental and unique in **index** and **data** tables. But flag table's id could be duplicated. For example, a program may use different flags to compile:

```
index: 123       jacobi     gcc        11                      345
data:  345       host1      3:21       2015-05-13 22:56:12     123
log:   123       345        "PASS"
flag:  11        "-g"
       11        "-mp"
       11        "-static"
```

So this program is compiled like:

```
gcc -g -mp -static jacobi.c
```

and the execution time is 3'21'' and finished by 2015-05-13 22:56:12.

The thing is, many people may run this program and may be due to various of reasons, the exact the same test may PASS or FAIL. And only the last run (based on the timestamp--date or the MAX(data_id) or the MAX(index_id) for the same test) will be showed in the webpage. How to determine whether tests are the same (DISTINCT)?
These field should be the same:

```
program, compiler and all the flags (no order issue)
```

So, you could see, the flags are stored in the flag table. I don't know how to correlate the index and flag table to find the same test.

Final example to show my expected output:

```
index: 123       jacobi     gcc        11                      345
data:  345       host1      3:21       2015-05-13 22:56:12     123
log:   123       345        "PASS"
flag:  11        "-g"
       11        "-mp"
       11        "-static"

index: 126       jacobi     gcc        15                      397
data:  397       host2      3:14       2015-05-13 23:13:28     126
log:   126       397        "FAIL"
flag:  15        "-g"
       15        "-mp"
       15        "-static"
```

Here, for these two records, they are the same test since they're using the same compiler to compile the same program with the same flags. But the second one is latest one. Because we can tell either from index_id, data_id or finishing date.

If there're 100000 records in my database and maybe 30000 of them are the same tests, how could I get these 30000 tests **with** their last run result, PASS or FAIL? Like:

```
gcc -g -mp -static jacobi.c  FAIL
gcc -g -mp         jacobi.c  PASS
gcc -O3            mm.c      PASS
...
```

I know it's wordy, your patience and any help are really appreciated!

Comment: Just add some tables called 'select', 'update' and 'delete' and you'll use every reserved word in sql known to mankind...

Comment: to stop me going insane trying to convert this into usable ddl statements - can you please add your create table statements, and some sample data to be inserted? :)

Comment: @ZoharPeled LOL... these are just for the questions... The real tables' names are more reasonable...

Comment: @pala_ Uh... no idea... I didn't create this database, I am just trying to use it...

Comment: @BrianYang: Whenever asking questions about sql, you should include the DDL and DML in your question if you need to provide sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appear to be attracted to self-flagellation. Anyway, first thing is first - assembling your flags into a string, and getting the results.:

```
select i.compiler, group_concat(f.flag_name order by f.flag_name asc separator ' ') flags, i.program, d.date, l.log
  from `index` i
    inner join `flag` f
      on i.flag_id = f.id
    inner join `data` d
      on i.data_id = d.id
    inner join `log` l
      on i.id = l.index_id
  group by i.id
```

the `order by` in the `group_concat` ensures the same set of flags will always appear in the same order.

This should give us a result that looks like `compiler | flag1 flag 2 ... | program | date`

Next step is to group by compiler, the flags and the program, and get the `max(date)`. We do this by querying the results of the first query.

```
select compiler, flags, program, max(`date`) max_date
  from (
    select i.compiler, group_concat(f.flag_name order by f.flag_name asc separator ' ') flags, i.program, d.date
      from `index` i
        inner join `flag` f
          on i.flag_id = f.id
        inner join `data` d
          on i.data_id = d.id
      group by i.id ) q
  group by compiler, flags, program;
```

We now know the most recent run time for each combo of compiler, flags and program.

We now need to join our first query back to this one, to find only the row with the max date, and the associated data:

```
select q1.* from (
  select i.compiler, group_concat(f.flag_name order by f.flag_name asc separator ' ') flags, i.program, d.date, l.log
      from `index` i
        inner join `flag` f
          on i.flag_id = f.id
        inner join `data` d
          on i.data_id = d.id
        inner join `log` l
          on i.id = l.index_id
      group by i.id
  ) q1
  inner join (
    select compiler, flags, program, max(`date`) max_date
      from (
        select i.compiler, group_concat(f.flag_name order by f.flag_name asc separator ' ') flags, i.program, d.date
          from `index` i
            inner join `flag` f
              on i.flag_id = f.id
            inner join `data` d
              on i.data_id = d.id
          group by i.id ) q
      group by compiler, flags, program ) q2
  on q1.compiler = q2.compiler 
    and q1.flags = q2.flags
    and q1.program = q2.program
    and q1.`date` = q2.max_date
```

sql fiddle is broken right now so i can't test this - but it should be pretty close.

Comment: Wow... I think it's pretty straight forward. My concern here is that will this have performance issue? Actually I tried some multiple select queries this morning, it's pretty slow... I am using python in the middle level to query the MySQL.

Comment: It won't be the most spectacular performing query. Because it can't be. There are joins on fields that can't be indexed (the `group_concat`). Hopefully tho each inner query shouldn't be too bad so long as the join fields are indexed, and it should reduce the dataset enough that the final join isn't horrible

Comment: Many thanks... I am gonna try this tomorrow and let you know. Our index and data tables are 10G and log table is about 300G...

Comment: Yuck. I'd suggest maintaining a most recent run table kept up to date with a trigger

Comment: @BrianYang how'd you go?

Comment: Busy... implementing other stuff, probably try this next week. Will let you know :-)